# Como acessar o nome e o endereço na Classe Cliente, e acessar descrição e preço na Classe Produto em Java, estando na Classe Caixa?

Tags: java, array, string, orientação-a-objetos, classes

eu tentei usar os seguintes comandos:

// Solicitando o nome do cliente
nome = input.toString();
compra[i].getCliente().setNome(nome);

```
            // Código do produto a ser comprado, que é o endereço da posição do vetor
            System.out.print("Produto: ");
            codigo = input.nextInt(); 
        
            //  compra[i].getProduto().Descricao = ;
```

Segue meus códigos abaixo:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Venda {
    int quantProduto = 5;
    int i;
    int numProdutos;
    double total;
    Date data = new Date(); 
    private Cliente cliente;
    private Produto [] produto;
            
    public Venda(Date data, Cliente cliente) {      
        this.cliente = new Cliente();
        this.data = data;               
    }
    
    public Venda(Date data, Cliente cliente, Produto[] produto) {       
        this.data = data;
        this.cliente = new Cliente();
        this.produto = new Produto[quantProduto];
        
    }
 
    public double getTotal() {
        return this.total;  
    }
    
    public void adicioneProduto(Produto p) {
        produto[i] = p;
        numProdutos++;
    }
    
    public Produto getProduto(int i) {
        return this.getProduto(i);
    }
    
    public int getNumProdutos() {
        return this.numProdutos;
    }
    
    public String imprimeVenda() {
        return data + " " + cliente + " " + produto[i]; 
    }       
}

public class Cliente {
    private String nome;
    private String endereco;
    
    public Cliente(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
        this.endereco = " ";
    }
    
    public Cliente() {
        this.nome = "";
        this.endereco = "";
    }
    
    public String getNome() {
        
        return this.nome;
        
    }
    
    public void setNome(String nome) {
        
        this.nome = nome;
    }
    
    public String imprimeCliente() {
        
        return "Cliente: " + this.nome + "\n Endereco: " + this.endereco;
    }
    

}


public class Produto {
    
    private String[] descricao= {"arroz", "feijao", "farinha", "macarrao", "açucar",
                                  "óleo", "vinagre", "azeite", "sal", "xerém"} ;
    private double[] preco = {5.00, 7.00, 4.50, 3.20, 2.50, 7.50, 2.00, 11.00, 1.50, 3.50};
    private int total;
    
        
    public Produto(String[] descricao, double[] preco) {        
        this.descricao = descricao;
        this.preco = preco;     
    }
    
    public double getTotal() {      
        return total;       
    }
    
    public double[] getPreco() {        
        return preco;       
    }
    
    public String imprimeProduto(String descricao, double total) {
        return "Produto: "  + this.descricao + " Total:" + this.total;
    }

}
```

---

```
import java.util.*;

public class Caixa {
    int quantProdutos = 5;
    Date data;
    int codigo;
    String nome;
    String iten;
    double preco;
    Venda [] compra;
    
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); 
    
    public boolean atendimento (String resposta) {  
                        
            if (resposta == "S" || resposta == "s") {
                return true;
            }
            
            else{           
                return false;               
            }
            
        }
    
    public <auxiliar> void Compra() {       
        int i = 0;
        String resposta;
        Venda [] compra = new Venda[quantProdutos] ;

        boolean atender = true;
        
        while (atender == true) {
            
            System.out.println("Continuar atendendo (S/Sim) (N/Não)?");
            resposta = input.nextLine();            
                        
            atender = atendimento(resposta);
            
            if (atender == true) {  
                
                // Solicitando o nome do cliente 
                nome = input.toString();
                compra[i].getCliente().setNome(nome);               
                                
                // Código do produto a ser comprado, que é o endereço da posição do vetor
                System.out.print("Produto: ");
                codigo = input.nextInt(); 
            
                //  compra[i].getProduto().Descricao = ;

                
                
            }
            
            if (i==quantProdutos) {
                quantProdutos = 2 * quantProdutos;              
                Venda [] auxiliar = new auxiliar [quantProdutos]; 
                this.compra = auxiliar;
            }
            i++;
        }
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você precisa criar uma instância da classe Cliente e da classe Produto e passar elas pra dentro da classe Caixa. Não sei quais são suas necessidades específicas mas umas das formas de se fazer isso é:

```
Cliente cliente = new Cliente ();
Produto produto = new produto ();

Caixa caixa = new Caixa();
caixa.compra(cliente, produto);
```

Comment: Oi Jaderson!

Boa noite!

Eu preciso fazer o seguinte:

) Implemente uma classe Loja que cria objetos do tipo Cliente, Produto e Venda e exibe na tela o cliente
que está realizando uma compra, os produtos comprados e o valor total da venda.
c) Nomeie os relacionamentos entre as classes.
d) Adicione uma classe Caixa à sua modelagem de classes. Um caixa contém uma coleção de vendas.

Comment: A classe Caixa deve possuir operações para
incluir um novo produto na venda atualmente aberta.
e) Adicione um construtor sobrecarregado à classe Venda de modo que se possa criar uma venda
passando-se para ela um arranjo de produtos ou a quantidade máxima de produtos da venda.

Comment: Depois que fiz as mudanças necessárias para que haja um compartilhamento dos dados, está dando um erro que não consigo retirar...

Answer (score 2):

Ewerton, seu código está um pouco confuso, mas acho que entendi o que você deseja fazer.

Antes de mais nada, você precisa passar os valores para os atributos da sua classe utilizando o construtor. Essa é a forma mais utilizada, pois você terá os valores carregados junto com a instância da classe.

Além disso, a sua classe produto não tem os gets e sets da propriedade **descricao**, que é a propriedade que você vai utilizar na classe Caixa para recuperar os dados através do índice do vetor.

Então acredito que você poderia fazer algo do tipo:

**Classe Produto**

```
public class Produto {

   private String[] descricao;
   private double[] preco;
   private int total;
    
   public Produto(String[] descricao, double[] preco) {        
       this.descricao = descricao;
       this.preco = preco;     
   }

   public double getTotal() {      
       return total;       
   }

   public double[] getPreco() {        
       return preco;       
   }

   public string[] getDesricao() {        
       return this.descricao;       
   }

   public String imprimeProduto(String descricao, double total) {
       return "Produto: "  + this.descricao + " Total:" + this.total;
   }

}
```

Depois de corrigir a classe Produto, dentro da classe Caixa você deve criar uma instância da classe Produto e passar os valores como parâmetros no construtor. Dessa forma:

**Classe Caixa**

```
// Suas variáveis
int i = 0;
String resposta;
Venda [] compra = new Venda[quantProdutos] ;

// Crie duas variáveis com os dados que serão passados para o construtor
String[] descricao = {"arroz", "feijao", "farinha", "macarrao", "açucar",
                              "óleo", "vinagre", "azeite", "sal", "xerém"} ;
double[] preco = {5.00, 7.00, 4.50, 3.20, 2.50, 7.50, 2.00, 11.00, 1.50, 3.50};

// Depois crie a instância da classe Produto passando os valores no construtor
Produto produto = new Produto(descricao, preco);

                 //

                //

// Código do produto a ser comprado, que é o endereço da posição do vetor
System.out.print("Produto: ");
codigo = input.nextInt(); 

//Agora você pode acessar os dados do Produto através da variável codigo:

String descricao = produto.getDescricao()[codigo];
String preco= produto.getPreco()[codigo];
```

Comment: Oi Jaderson!

Muito obrigado por sua ajuda!

Comment: Deu certo Ewerton? Se consegui te ajudar, marque a pergunta como aceita. Obrigado!